# Parse all stored procedures in a database

Tags: sql-server, parsing, stored-procedures

Does anyone know of a way to verify the correctness of the queries in all stored procedures in a database?
I'm thinking of the scenario where if you modify something in a code file, simply doing a rebuild would show you compilation errors that point you to places where you need to fix things. In a database scenario, say if you modify a table and remove a column which is used in a stored procedure you won't know anything about this problem until the first time that procedure would run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically check (parse) the validity of a TSQL statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084387/how-can-i-programmatically-check-parse-the-validity-of-a-tsql-statement) @CyberDude - You can use `SET NOEXEC ON` but I think the best way is to write a utility to actually try and execute them and rollback.

Comment: I guess I could build a dynamic script that lists all procedures and tries to execute them. One interesting part would be to mock all required parameters though... Another way would be to retrieve the procedure text and try to do an `ALTER PROCEDURE` but not changing anything inside.

Comment: Parsing is a useful first step, and you could parse revised stored procedures to validate their syntax.  But loading them into the DB will do that, so this isn't much of a win.  Verifying that they work by some regular method seems much more useful.  The "unit testing" answer provided by OMG Ponies is pretty good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is what unit testing is for.  Stored procedures and functions often require parameters to be set, and if the stored procedure or function encapsulates dynamic SQL--there's a chance that a [corner] case is missed.

Also, all you mention is checking for basic errors--nothing about validating the data returned.  For example - I can change the precision on a numeric column...

This also gets into the basic testing that should occur for the immediate issue, and regression testing to ensure there aren't unforeseen issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could create all of your objects with SCHEMABINDING, which would prevent you from changing any underlying tables without dropping and recreating the views and procedures built on top of them.

Depending on your development process, this could be pretty cumbersome. I offer it as a solution though, because if you want to ensure the correctness of all procedures in the db, this would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example on MSDN (SQL Server 2012). I guess it can be used in some scenarios:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

SELECT p.name, r.* 
FROM sys.procedures AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(p.object_id, 0) AS r;
```

Source: [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878236.aspx)