# SQL Server Stored Procedure Compile-time Validation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know how to get compile time validation of parameters being passed to a stored procedure.  Example If Proc1 calls Proc2 but specifies an invalid parameter name for Proc2.  Currently I find out at run-time.  Is there a way to find out when I'm creating Proc1?

Thanks much,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible. For the scenario you give.

```
create proc dbo.foo 
@a int
as
select 1

go

create proc dbo.bar
as
exec dbo.foo @b=10
```

The only way of detecting the error is to execute it. Obviously you could execute in a transaction that rolls back and automate these tests.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  You understand the problem exactly.  I don't want to perform an execute even if it is in a transaction simply because I would have to write execute statements for each stored proc.  Are you certain that it is not possible?  I thought that another tool did the validation, such as Visual Studio but not sure.  I wonder how another tool would do it if in fact they do.  I may write  an app to loop through all procs and call each of them in a transaction.

Comment: @Thomas - I tried `SET NOEXEC ON` and `SET PARSEONLY ON` as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084387/how-can-i-programmatically-check-parse-the-validity-of-a-tsql-statement and neither gave any error hence my conclusion. Looking at it again though I see the SSMS intellisense gives the message `@b is not a parameter for procedure foo`. I'm not sure if there is any way to leverage the checking it is doing there. Additionally running `SET FMTONLY ON exec dbo.bar` returns an error message.