# Validate Oracle Sql Conditional Expression in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Is it possible to validate Conditional Expressions of Oracle - SQL in a Silverlight app. In my project i am allowing the user to enter the custom SQL -conditional expression for fetching the data, for which i wish to provide a validate option for the user.

Thanks & Regards
Rithesh Krishnan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do SQL validation from Silverlight, it will have to be done on the server.

There is a lot of interesting discussion about SQL validation techniques in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084387/how-can-i-programmatically-check-parse-the-validity-of-a-tsql-statement). Most of it is not applicable to Oracle however.

If you need to support both, you can create a generic solution using `transactions and rollbacks`. I use `ADO.NET` classes in the following example, but they are interchangeable with their counterparts in `ODP.NET`

```
using (DbConnection connection =
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        DbTransaction transaction = null;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            command.CommandText = "The SQL to validate";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //The SQL is valid
        }
        catch
        {
            // The SQL is not valid
        }
        finally
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }

}
```

To provide the user with feedback, you can implement your own notification, or if you want it to look like a validation error: implement [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx) on your Binding target and set errors in the callback from your server.