# Is there a way how to check if the operation is valid before is called?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there a way how to find if the statement is valid before is called? For example when you are trying to **delete column which does not exist** or when you are trying to **delete record which is linked by foreign key and you are forbidden to delete it.** Something like clicking on Parse (Ctrl+F5) button but called from a code. (Ideally to be possible to call it from C# code by using [command class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.90).aspx).)

Something like

```
Exec sp_canIdoIt("SQL statement").
```

Without actually calling the statement "SQL statement".

I made some googling and

[PARSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx)  leads to something completely different.

[CTRL+F5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx) shortcut does not help much.

I would really like to be able to call database and be sure it will not return me an error.

Comment: Why not just handle errors if they happen?

Comment: ADO.NET cannot see into the future. How could it know  if something exists without asking the database?

Comment: do it in a transaction and rollback your changes.

Comment: @tim-schmelter I am not telling without asking DB I am asking if it is possible to ask database if it is valid to call some statement.

Comment: 1) You check, and there's no row preventing deletion via Foreign Key, 2) Someone else inserts a row that now references the row you're planning to delete, 3) You try to perform the actual delete and it fails. No amount of pre-checking can prevent these sort of scenarios.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever you are right. I can not avoid errors I must work with them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right -- the best way to do it, if you need to ensure that all your steps or statement blocks "work" or must explode - is to do it all in one database transaction, then commit the transaction.  If the commit fails (catching it with exceptions in your code) -- then you know it didn't work.     Let the database handle consistency, referential integrity and all the FK constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a transaction and rollback the change, but that would still return you an error.

I think, perhaps, that you're thinking about this wrong.

An `SqlException` can be handled or unhandled with a `try-catch` block. Why not just handle the error case instead of performing strange psuedo logic to test the validity of something? You can have your function that returns a success status based on your error.

If you get an `SqlException` on `connection.Open()`, your database in inaccessible. If you get an `SqlException` when committing the query, then there is a problem with the query. Just handle that case, return some kind of errorresult enumeration, and do something else with it.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* a way, and that's using NOEXEC.    But -- don't vote mine as the accepted answer, because what C Bauer is suggesting is the correct way to go -- catch those exceptions in your code and act on it.    It's the very reason we're given error handling.

But here is a writeup on NOEXEC, if for some reason, you're re-engineering SSMS Query Analyzer into your own little app.

http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/07/validating-sql-query-programmatically.html

[How can I programmatically check (parse) the validity of a TSQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084387/how-can-i-programmatically-check-parse-the-validity-of-a-tsql-statement)